# shared preferences not working in Samsung Phones Galaxy Nexus and Samsung GT P7500

Tags: preferences, shared

I am trying to store few key and values in **shared preferences** and trying to retrive back from preferences, same code works fine in all devices including HTC,Motorola,LG phone but  not working in samsung phones. 
Data is not stored properly or not retrieved from share preferences in the above mentioned samsung phones. Is this a known issue in Samsung phones ? or is there a specific way to handle shared preferences in samsung phones ?